# Getting a row count with an ordered result of union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that has 6 unions in it to get six different levels of data and then sort it.

Updated dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/zNH3Xjog

This is the base data:

| SHELFLOCID | PARENTSHELFLOCID | DEPTH | PICKSORTVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 33 | 55 | 2 | 1 |
| 88 | 55 | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 77 | 11 | 2 | 1 |

I need to use that query to update another field in the database with the sorted order, so want to return a counter and use that and the ID field to update.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    LEVEL1_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL2SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL3SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL4SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL5SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL6SORT,
    LEVEL1_DATA.SHELFLOCID
FROM
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL1_DATA
WHERE
    LEVEL1_DATA.DEPTH = 1
    AND LEVEL1_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891
  
UNION

SELECT
    LEVEL2_LEVEL1.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
    LEVEL2_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL2SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL3SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL4SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL5SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL6SORT,
    LEVEL2_DATA.SHELFLOCID
FROM
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL2_DATA
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL2_LEVEL1 ON LEVEL2_LEVEL1.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL2_DATA.PARENTSHELFLOCID
WHERE
    LEVEL2_DATA.DEPTH = 2
    AND LEVEL2_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891

UNION

SELECT
    LEVEL3_LEVEL1.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
    LEVEL3_LEVEL2.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL2SORT,
    LEVEL3_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL3SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL4SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL5SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL6SORT,
    LEVEL3_DATA.SHELFLOCID
FROM
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL3_DATA
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL3_LEVEL2 ON LEVEL3_LEVEL2.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL3_DATA.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL3_LEVEL1 ON LEVEL3_LEVEL1.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL3_LEVEL2.PARENTSHELFLOCID
WHERE
    LEVEL3_DATA.DEPTH = 3
    AND LEVEL3_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891

UNION

SELECT
    LEVEL4_LEVEL1.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
    LEVEL4_LEVEL2.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL2SORT,
    LEVEL4_LEVEL3.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL3SORT,
    LEVEL4_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL4SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL5SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL6SORT,
    LEVEL4_DATA.SHELFLOCID
FROM
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL4_DATA
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL4_LEVEL3 ON LEVEL4_LEVEL3.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL4_DATA.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL4_LEVEL2 ON LEVEL4_LEVEL2.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL4_LEVEL3.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL4_LEVEL1 ON LEVEL4_LEVEL1.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL4_LEVEL2.PARENTSHELFLOCID
WHERE
    LEVEL4_DATA.DEPTH = 4
    AND LEVEL4_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891

UNION

SELECT
    LEVEL5_LEVEL1.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
    LEVEL5_LEVEL2.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL2SORT,
    LEVEL5_LEVEL3.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL3SORT,
    LEVEL5_LEVEL4.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL4SORT,
    LEVEL5_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL5SORT,
    CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL6SORT,
    LEVEL5_DATA.SHELFLOCID
FROM
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL5_DATA
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL5_LEVEL4 ON LEVEL5_LEVEL4.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL5_DATA.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL5_LEVEL3 ON LEVEL5_LEVEL3.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL5_LEVEL4.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL5_LEVEL2 ON LEVEL5_LEVEL2.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL5_LEVEL3.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL5_LEVEL1 ON LEVEL5_LEVEL1.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL5_LEVEL2.PARENTSHELFLOCID
WHERE
    LEVEL5_DATA.DEPTH = 5
    AND LEVEL5_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891

UNION

SELECT
    LEVEL6_LEVEL1.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
    LEVEL6_LEVEL2.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL2SORT,
    LEVEL6_LEVEL3.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL3SORT,
    LEVEL6_LEVEL4.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL4SORT,
    LEVEL6_LEVEL5.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL5SORT,
    LEVEL6_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL6SORT,
    LEVEL6_DATA.SHELFLOCID
FROM
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL6_DATA
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL6_LEVEL5 ON LEVEL6_LEVEL5.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL6_DATA.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL6_LEVEL4 ON LEVEL6_LEVEL4.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL6_LEVEL5.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL6_LEVEL3 ON LEVEL6_LEVEL3.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL6_LEVEL4.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL6_LEVEL2 ON LEVEL6_LEVEL2.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL6_LEVEL3.PARENTSHELFLOCID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL6_LEVEL1 ON LEVEL6_LEVEL1.SHELFLOCID = LEVEL6_LEVEL2.PARENTSHELFLOCID
WHERE
    LEVEL6_DATA.DEPTH = 6
    AND LEVEL6_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891
ORDER BY
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

This will return a result set that sorts on the first 6 columns, which are values that are pre-sorted (using the PICKSORTVALUE and the DISPLAYORDER) in the save operation from the program itself.

The results look like this:

| LEVEL1SORT | LEVEL2SORT | LEVEL3SORT | LEVEL4SORT | LEVEL5SORT | LEVEL6SORT | SHELFLOCID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 55 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 33 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 88 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 55 |

I then want to use a row counter and the SHELFLOCID field in an update query:

```
UPDATE INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS 
SET PICKORDER = 1, 2, 3, 4,etc
WHERE SHELFLOCID = 55, 33, 88, 11,etc
```

I can step through the results individually and update the records, which takes about 4 seconds to process, however I'm looking to something to do it at the database level.

It must be done in a single query and can't have multiple parts in the query.

The updated database would look like this:

| SHELFLOCID | PICKORDER |
| --- | --- |
| 55 | 1 |
| 33 | 2 |
| 88 | 3 |
| 11 | 4 |
| 77 | 5 |

Can this be done?

Comment: Can't you use `ROW_NUMBER` to number them?

Comment: Sample input data for all tables would help immensely

Comment: Yes, that's my assumption, but I tried various ways to get it into the data but couldn't make it work, it's not something I have done before. I still then didn't know how to update with the select.

Comment: @Charlieface I thought the table would help, that is pretty much exactly what the data looks like, I'll add the individual lines as well.

Comment: We need to be able to recreate your query, perhaps in https://dbfiddle.uk, and get the results you want, ideally it would be `CREATE TABLE... INSERT...` statements. Sorry just realized it's actually all one table.

Comment: @Charlieface I've added the data now

Comment: @Darren, Can you try creating CTE and apply row_number() for that. 
Ex: 

With cte_INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS as (
select * from INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS
union
..... all union details)

select *, row_number() from cte_INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS;

Comment: The data you have given is missing columns. But anyway the sort doesn't seem to match the data: you would get `11, 33, 55` etc not `55, 33, 88`. It seems you actually want to sort by depth also

Comment: Even with depth-first traversal, I don't get why 55 comes before 11. You could simplify with a recursive CTE and using `hierarchyid`, just not sure the ordering https://dbfiddle.uk/HmV9T_Y6

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry you were correct, I forgot the depth column, which is what puts the sort at the right level

Comment: Updated with dbfiddle with correct data

Comment: @darren in your fiddle you check `WHERE loc.PARENTSHELFLOCID IS NULL` but you don't have any data with NULLs. Change it to `WHERE loc.PARENTSHELFLOCID = 0` or change your data back to include the NULLs.

Comment: @MatBailie dbfiddle is fixed, using the answer below. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE) with the **ROW_NUMBER()** function to generate the row numbers for your sorted data and then use that information to update the **PICKORDER** field. Below is the SQL query

```
WITH SortedData AS (
    SELECT
        SHELFLOCID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY LEVEL1SORT, LEVEL2SORT, LEVEL3SORT, LEVEL4SORT, LEVEL5SORT, LEVEL6SORT
        ) AS RowNum
    FROM (
        -- Your existing query goes here
        SELECT
            LEVEL1_DATA.PICKSORTVALUE AS LEVEL1SORT,
            CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL2SORT,
            CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL3SORT,
            CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL4SORT,
            CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL5SORT,
            CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS LEVEL6SORT,
            LEVEL1_DATA.SHELFLOCID
        FROM
            INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS LEVEL1_DATA
        WHERE
            LEVEL1_DATA.DEPTH = 1
            AND LEVEL1_DATA.LOCATIONID = 24541891

        UNION

        -- Your other UNION queries go here
        -- (Levels 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    ) AS CombinedData
)
UPDATE INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS AS ISL
SET PICKORDER = SD.RowNum
FROM SortedData AS SD
WHERE ISL.SHELFLOCID = SD.SHELFLOCID;
```

Comment: That is similar to what I attempted, it gives the error: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 266
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @darren then remove the `order by 1,2,3,4,5,6` as it serves no purpose within an update statement.

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that and came back to make the same comment. However I get a new error in the UPDATE section: "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 158
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." It has the AS ISL bit underlined.

Comment: I removed the AS from the SQL, fixed the ORDER BY and it worked. Updated fiddle in the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your multiple joins using a recursive CTE. And for ordering you can concatenate the `PICKSORTVALUE` column into a `hierarchyid` and generate a row-number based off that. Then just rejoin it back to the main table to make the update.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      loc.SHELFLOCID,
      CAST(CONCAT('/', loc.PICKSORTVALUE, '/') AS varchar(4000)) AS hierarchy
    FROM INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS loc
    WHERE loc.PARENTSHELFLOCID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      loc.SHELFLOCID,
      CAST(CONCAT(cte.hierarchy, loc.PICKSORTVALUE, '/') AS varchar(4000))
    FROM INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS loc
    JOIN cte ON cte.SHELFLOCID = loc.PARENTSHELFLOCID
),
Numbered AS (
    SELECT
      cte.SHELFLOCID,
      cte.hierarchy,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(cte.hierarchy AS hierarchyid)) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
UPDATE loc
SET PICKORDER = Numbered.rn
OUTPUT inserted.*, Numbered.hierarchy   -- output data to show what happened
FROM INVENTORYSHELFLOCATIONS loc
JOIN Numbered ON Numbered.SHELFLOCID = loc.SHELFLOCID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/wqjGg-1L)